# Compiling kafka schema-registry fails for building kafka-connect-hdfs

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to build kafka-connect-hdfs by following [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/wiki/FAQ) FAQ.

While trying to compile schema-registry, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven- 
 compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project kafka- 
 schema-registry-client: Compilation failure
 [ERROR] /Users/workspace-name/kafka-connect/schema- registry/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/s ecurity/basicauth/SaslBasicAuthCredentialProvider.java:[40,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method 
loadClientContext(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>)
[ERROR]   location: class org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext
```

Are any modifications required? Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the pre-built binaries available at https://www.confluent.io/download/ ?

Comment: We are using kafka 0.11 version and kafka-connect binaries (connect-standalone.sh and connect-distributed.sh). Hence trying to build kafka-connect-hdfs separately and plugin with our existing platform.

Comment: The Confluent Platform download includes the pre-compiled binaries for the HDFS connector. You can opt to use the whole platform, or you can just take the binaries from the distribution and use them within your existing installation.

Comment: Thanks! I have download confluent 4.0.1 binaries to see if it would work with kafka 0.11.0.x version. Even with the binaries, the way to use kafka hdfs connector is through confluent.sh. Is there a way to start kafka-connect-hdfs directly without using confluent binary? Appreciate your inputs! Thanks

Comment: `kafka-connect-hdfs` is a JAR that you use with Kafka Connect. You can run Connect (`connect-standalone` / `connect-distributed`) the same whether it's Confluent distribution or a different one. `confluent.sh` is the Confluent CLI, which is just a wrapper to help you start up the services.

Comment: Confluent 4.0.1 is meant to be used with Kafka 1.0.1... You need to download or build the 3.3.1 release